# int list won't display in console application

Tags: c#

I come from a C++ background creating basic 2D games with it, but I am trying to teach myself C# to a point to where I can get the most basic of jobs using it. I am not in school but I am following the Problems on ProjectEuler.net.

The problem question is commented into the code. I can't tell whether I solved it or not because I can't get the numbers to display from a list into the console application.

I've tried writing to console directly from the variable value with `Console.WriteLine` but I'm not having any luck. I've also tried converting all int list values to a string value and displaying them but that also didn't work.
I'm not looking for the answer to number 4 just looking to display the list so I can find the answer on my own.

Why can't I get the list to write to the Console?

Any help is appreciated!

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* A palindromic number reads the same both ways. 
             * The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
                    Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers. */
            // 100 x 100 = 10000
            // 999 x 999 = 998001

        List<int> palindromeContainer = new List<int>();
        int Increment = 2;
        int Holder = 0;
        for (int i = 100; i <= 999; ++i)
        {
            int j = i;
            while (j <= 999)
            {
                do
                {      Holder = i * j; // Gets all Possible Combinations of i * j          

                    if ((Holder % Increment) != 0) // Checks for Prime Numbers 
                    {
                        ++Increment;
                    }
                    else if (Increment == Holder - 1 && Holder % Increment != 0 )
                    {
                        palindromeContainer.Add(Holder);
                        Increment = 2;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (Increment == Holder - 1 && Holder % Increment == 0)
                    { 
                        Increment = 2;
                        break;
                    }
                } while (Increment < Holder);
                ++j;
            }
        }
        palindromeContainer.Sort();
        foreach (int line in palindromeContainer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);  // Display  all items in list
        }
```

Comment: Did you run the code in a debugger and check it does what you think it does?

Comment: Your console output code is just fine.  I don't think `palindromeContainer` contains anything.

Comment: It sound's like your `palindromeContainer` is probably not populated like your think.

Comment: I just ran your code and your if else conditions are never met. It looks like your `do while` is stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: You set `Increment` to `2` and `Holder` to `0`, then you have in your if conditions `(Holder % Increment) != 0` and `Increment == Holder - 1`, neither of which are true, so none of your code in the loop executes. Your loop then exits because `Increment < Holder` is false, and then `palindromeContainer` is empty.

Comment: Thanks guys sorry for the wasted time. What everyone said helped me to realize the simple mistake I made with the infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly comment out your loop logic and test without:

```
List<int> palindromeContainer = new List<int>();
palindromeContainer.Add(2);
palindromeContainer.Add(1);
palindromeContainer.Sort();
foreach (int line in palindromeContainer)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);  // Display  all items in list
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

This will output to the console. Then you will know this is working and console output is not the problem.